# How to prove the size of supremum of non-empty subset of R?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I am confused on this:

Suppose A is a non-empty set of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite supremum sup A = L. Then how do I prove that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists a \in A $ s.t $L-a < \epsilon$. Maybe I can assume that $L-a>\epsilon$ or $L-a=\epsilon$ for a contradiction, but I am not sure how to proceed. Intuitively it seems to say that the difference between the supremum and any element of the subset can be as small as we want. How should I prove this point?

Comment: It follows directly from the definition of supremum, doesn't it? What _is_ your definition of supremum?

Comment: Supremum is the least upper bound. I understand that it is the "least" upper bound, but how can I argue that with contradiction?

Comment: If there existed $\epsilon>0$ for which that statement was not true, then $L-\epsilon$ would be an upper bound. So $L$ would not be the _least_ upper bound.